# SharePoint 2013 Permission for AD Group not working

Tags: sharepoint-server, permissions, active-directory

User dose not exist in AD group user list still have access to SharePoint.

There is one AD group "A". if we add that group in SharePoint permission. All group member users get access to SharePoint along with **non member** of that AD group "A".

if we remove that group from SharePoint access removed for all member of AD group along with **non member** of AD group "A".

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: is any one know how nonmember of AD group are getting access?

Answer (score 7):

On your site, navigate to Site Settings > Site Permissions

[image]

In the ribbon, find and click "Check Permissions".

[image]

The return will show how the user have access to your site.

Comment: we have checked that too. if we are adding AD group non member of AD group are getting access.

Answer (score 3):

Another thing to check. Check the permission on site collection, if you allowed **NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users** or Added **Everyone** in somewhere the site collection. if yes then user will get the access without adding him individually or AD groups etc.

Answer (score 0):

Has the user logged in and then out of his account since the AD group changes? If he/she has, then you may need to change the timeout configuration of your SharePoint farm. I have included some PowerShell below to illustrate;

```
$sts = Get-SPSecurityTokenServiceConfig
$sts.FormsTokenLifetime = (New-TimeSpan -minutes 2)
$sts.WindowsTokenLifetime = (New-TimeSpan -minutes 2)
$sts.LogonTokenCacheExpirationWindow = (New-TimeSpan -minutes 1)
$sts.Update()
iisreset
```

Here is an [MSDN blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jesusfer/2015/08/27/sharepoint-2013-authentication-lifetime-settings/) explaining this in more depth.

Answer (score 0):

Double-check your AD structure on Active Directory repository to see whether there are sub-groups or users below the level of the AD group you are assigning.

If you can only access SharePoint's central administration for now, have a look at **User Profile Service Application** > **Configure Synchronization Connection** > Populate Containers with proper AD synchronization account and look for whether there occurs multi-level hierarchy where a sub-group could include your "non member" user.

[image]